# Divide html page with multiple shapes using css

Tags: html, css

I want to design a page like this below. Any suggestion how to do that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CTBg.png)

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you to check the columns in Bootstrap 3/4 (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns), there is a section to make offset columns, if you have to do some server side pre render you will have to calculate this dynamically, otherwise, just use offset for desktop and normal column disposition for mobile/tablet, good luck.

Comment: Hi 
Thanks for your valuable comment. But need suggestion how to design the page with those different shapes.

Comment: Turns out I have this wonderful article about drawing shapes in CSS3 in my bookmarks (https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) take a look and if you need anymore help, don't hesitate on leaving a message.